# Is tightening this nut impossible?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet, plumbing-fixture, fitting

There is water dripping out of the part of the t-valve adapter connected to the toilet tank. The angle required to tighten the bolt with a tool makes it (seemingly) impossible.

Wrench? Not enough space to turn it. Pliers? Too big to reach it.  It’s been tightened by hand as much as possible, but still leaks.

Even when I remove the other connections, the problem is still the lack of space to work with.

Any ideas for a solution? Thanks, kind folks.

[image: toilet at a glance]
[image: rear of toilet near the wall]
[image: showing the nut that needs tightening]
[image: tool in hand for scale]

Comment: Does the adjustable wrench shown open wide enough to fit around the nut?

Comment: @JimStewart It does.

Comment: If your adjustable wrench is too thick, fixed size "thin" or "low profile" open-ended wrenches are easily available at tool/big box stores. There are also "basin wrenches" and "crows foot" wrenches for right-angle work.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding the problem, but remember that turning a wrench/spanner over changes the angle at which it approaches the workpiece.

Answer (score 12):

The installation instructions show a rubber washer in that T connection to the toilet inlet, so once you have it finger tight, it should only need another 1/4 turn or so with the wrench to make a seal.

[image]

***Tools***

There are some specialized tools available for tightening nuts in tight spaces:

One is a "basin wrench" (example only):

[image]

More generally, you can get "crows foot" wrenches, which attach to a standard ratchet extension for right-angle work (example only):

[image]

***Alternate Part Eliminates Need For Specialized Tools***

Also, the  manufacturer website indicates they sell an "alternate" T which **seems to connect right at the shut off valve** instead of at the toilet inlet. That may be your easiest bet.

[image]

[image]

***Related Questions***:

[how-can-i-fasten-nuts-in-narrow-places-when-installing-a-faucet?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/61941/how-can-i-fasten-nuts-in-narrow-places-when-installing-a-faucet)

[how-to-tighten-fitting-on-pipe-in-very-small-space](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/107108/how-to-tighten-fitting-on-pipe-in-very-small-space?rq=1)

Comment: I'm not really understanding why that "alternate" tee would have any 1/2" connections at all. If I'm looking at this right, the outlet of the shutoff valve is 3/8", that end of the feed line is 3/8", and the seat line is 3/8". Seems like a 3/8"-all-around tee (like [this one at Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-3-8-in-x-3-8-in-x-3-8-in-Compression-x-Compression-Brass-T-Fitting-CT2-666X-P/202495893)) would be what you'd need to move the seat line so it taps in directly after the shutoff. And then you can just hand-tighten the line to the tank, without any obstructing tees.

Comment: @FeRD According to their website, the company's standard T valve is 7/8" x 7/8" x 1/2", so perhaps the line to their bidet has a 1/2" connector rather than a 3/8" connector. I agree in the OP's photos it looks more like a 3/8" connection. The "alternate" T pictured does seem to include both male and female 1/2" to 3/8" adapters.